# Match all regex start with but not end with characters

Tags: php, regex

i have an array of words 
i want to match all with starting `'___'`
but some words also having `'___'` at the end . 
but i do not want to match these words

here is my word list

```
___apis
___db_tables
___groups
___inbox_messages
___sent_messages
___todo
___users
___users_groups
____4underscorestarting
sinan
sssssssssss
test_______dfg
testttttt
tet____
tttttttttt
uuuuuuuu
vvvvvvvvvvvv
wwwwwwww
zzzzzzzzzz
```

i want to match only these words

```
___apis
___db_tables
___groups
___inbox_messages
___sent_messages
___todo
___users
___users_groups
```

i do not want to match these words

```
tet____
test_______dfg
____4underscorestarting
```

this is how it looks like when i try

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
^___[a-z].*
```

this should do it for you.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/hHRg8d/1

Comment: can you also tell me how to oposite of it

Comment: @c_minor_team use negative lookahead for opposite

Answer (score 2):

The solution using `preg_grep` function:

```
// $arr is your initial array of words
$matched = preg_grep("/^_{3}[^_].*/", $arr);
print_r($matched);
```

The output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => ___apis
    [1] => ___db_tables
    [2] => ___groups
    [3] => ___inbox_messages
    [4] => ___sent_messages
    [5] => ___todo
    [6] => ___users
    [7] => ___users_groups
)
```

**Update:** To get the *opposite* matches use one of the following:

- regex pattern:
  `/^(?!_{3})\w*/`
- set the third argument of `preg_grep` function as `PREG_GREP_INVERT`(... `preg_grep("/^_{3}[^_].*/", $arr, PREG_GREP_INVERT)`)

http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-grep.php

Comment: @c_minor_team, you're welcome. Also, check my pattern for the opposite matches

Comment: To get the *opposite* you can also use `preg_grep` third parameter.

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte, let's do it. Edited. Thanks for the hint

Answer (score 0):

```
    ^_{3}.*[^(_{3})]$
```

1. Starts(^) with 3 '_' _{3}
2. Can contain anything in the middle .*
3. Does not end($) in 3 '*' [^(*{3}]

Comment: You don't have well understand what character classes are. To give an idea, writing `[^(_{3})]` is the same than writing `[^)(}{3_]`.